# PDO DB connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need some help with my DB connection.

I've got my config.php:

```
namespace App\Core;


class config
{
    private $db;
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $charset;
    private $opt;
    private $dsn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = 'example';
        $this->host = '127.0.0.1';
        $this->user = 'root';
        $this->password = '';
        $this->charset = 'utf8';
        $this->dsn = "mysql:host=$this->host;DBName=$this->db;charset=$this->charset;";

        $this->opt = array(
            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false
        );
    }

    // getters
    public function db()
    {
        return $this->db;
    }

    public function host()
    {
        return $this->host;
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function password()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function charset()
    {
        return $this->charset;
    }

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->opt;
    }

    public function dsn()
    {
        return $this->dsn;
    }
}
```

I chose to use a config class.

Then I do also have a DBHandler class. This is where I make my PDO connection, and probally where it goes wrong.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->config = new config();

    try {
        $this->PDO = new \PDO($this->config->dsn(), $this->config->user(), $this->config->password(), $this->config->options());
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
    }
}

public static function getInstance()
{
    if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
        self::$instance = new DBHandler();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

public function connect()
{
    return $this->PDO;
}
```

Then I also have a DBHelper what is basicly my CRUD class, here I write all my queries and this is the file I call in all my normal PHP files like "index.php".

Whenever I try to run a query I get an error, so I var_dumped my $db and got this error out of it:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in D:\App\Core\DBHelper.php:28 Stack trace: #0 D:\App\Core\DBHelper.php(28): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM u...') #1 D:\App\Core\DBHelper.php(55): App\Core\DBHelper->userQuery('SELECT * FROM u...') #2 D:\App\index.php(28): App\Core\DBHelper->select('users', '*', 'userName', NULL) #3 {main} thrown in D:\App\Core\DBHelper.php on line 28

Can anyone tell me where it goes wrong?

Comment: Off topic: normally you would call getters more like ... `getDb()`, `getDatabase()` talking about the config class or if you use  setters `setDd(...)`, `setDatabase(...)` they you directly can see the function of the function

Comment: The dsn `DBName=$this->db` try it with lowercase `dbname=$this->db` not sure if it matters

Comment: @Raymond, you are right, `DBName` causes `Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected`. When the database does not exist, then I get error 1049.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the help I do connect with the database now. Just have an SQL error.

Comment: It should be `dbname`, not `DBName`. [Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php).